# Strange pandas behaviour. character is found where it does not exist

Tags: python, pandas

I aim to write a function to apply to an entire dataframe. Each column is checked to see if it contains the currency symbol '$' and remove it.

Surprisingly, a case like:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2021-01-10').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
print(dates)
```

output:

`Index(['01-01-2021', '02-01-2021', '03-01-2021', '04-01-2021', '05-01-2021', '06-01-2021', '07-01-2021', '08-01-2021', '09-01-2021', '10-01-2021'], dtype='object')`

But when I do:

```
dates.str.contains('$').all()
```

It returns `True`. Why???

Comment: `str.contains` by default assumes you are passing a regex pattern, in which $ has a special meaning. Try `dates.str.contains('$',regex=False).all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) uses regex (by default), not just a raw string. And `$` means the end of the line in regex (intuitively or not, all strings have "the end"). To check the symbol `"$"` you need to escape it:

```
dates.str.contains('\$').all()
```

Or you can use `regex=False` argument of the `.contains()`:

```
dates.str.contains('$', regex=False).all()
```

Both options return `False`.

Comment: OMG. Thanks. I should have thought of that. I am checking for other currencies as well. I will just pass `regex=False`